# Elasticsearch : Indexing rate slows down gradually

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing to ES from Spark streaming at a rate of around 80,000 EPS.
which was running fine earlier, but recently the indexing rate slows down gradually and the results in spark-jobs piling up.

what are the cluster settings which I can tweak/verify to address this issue

[image]

cluster settings :-

```
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "routing": {
        "allocation": {
          "cluster_concurrent_rebalance": "160",
          "node_concurrent_recoveries": "2",
          "disk": {
            "threshold_enabled": "true",
            "watermark": {
              "low": "85%",
              "high": "95%"
            }
          },
          "node_initial_primaries_recoveries": "40",
          "enable": "all"
        }
      }
    },
    "indices": {
      "breaker": {
        "fielddata": {
          "limit": "50%"
        }
      },
      "recovery": {
        "concurrent_streams": "80",
        "max_bytes_per_sec": "50mb"
      },
      "store": {
        "throttle": {
          "max_bytes_per_sec": "500gb"
        }
      }
    },
    "threadpool": {
      "bulk": {
        "queue_size": "5000",
        "size": "40",
        "type": "fixed"
      }
    },
    "discovery": {
      "zen": {
        "minimum_master_nodes": "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "transient": {
    "cluster": {
      "routing": {
        "allocation": {
          "enable": "all"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

cluster status:-

```
{
  "cluster_name": "**********",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 105,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 100,
  "active_primary_shards": 7315,
  "active_shards": 7330,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100
}
```